# You must specify a framework in '.storybook/main.js' config but is specified yet

Tags: webpack, expo, storybook

I'm facing problems running storybook when I upgrade my project to EXPO SKD 48. In previous versions it was working with no roblems, but
when I run `npm run storybook` console throws me an error:

> Error: You must specify a framework in '.storybook/main.js' config.

But my `storybook/main.js` has still a framework.
Here's my code:

`storybook/main.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  framework: '@storybook/react',
  stories: [
    '../src/components/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'
  ],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
    '@storybook/addon-react-native-web',
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-postcss',
      options: {
        postcssLoaderOptions: {
          implementation: require('postcss')
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  core: {
    builder: 'webpack5'
  }
}
```

`package.json`

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.0.4",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/cli-debugger-ui": "^10.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0", 
    "expo": "~48.0.15",
    "expo-application": "~5.1.1",
    "expo-asset": "~8.9.1",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-device": "~5.2.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.4",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.7",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.11",
    "sentry-expo": "~6.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.20",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.20",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.4.20",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^6.4.0",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.20",
    "@storybook/addon-postcss": "^2.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-react-native-web": "^0.0.18",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^7.0.7",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/react-native": "^5.3.27",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.54.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.54.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.3.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
```

In fact, my storybook dependencies hasn't changes after upgrade expo, but maybe problems with webpack?

Comment: I was having a similar sounding problem.  In my case I had to add the missing framework attribute to main.js.  By the way, I'm using a version 7 storybook.  The statement I used was " framework: '@storybook/react-webpack5',  "  I also deletes the core atttibute.  This was apparently a change in version 7 of storybook.  If you're using that version, I suggest you try those changes to your main.js file. Thing started working for me once I made those changes.